# Standard Rails Gem for storing what User created/updated/deleted any Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version-control, activerecord

What's the standard/best option out there for this kind of version control?  The main thing I'm looking for is to track what user edited a record.

I've seen these so far and am wondering what your take is:

- [PaperTrail](http://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)
- [ActsAsAudited](http://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited)
- [VestalVersions](http://github.com/laserlemon/vestal_versions)

Answer (score 1):

For stamping user_ids onto rows there is the the userstamp plugin

http://github.com/delynn/userstamp

EDIT:

Based on the requirement mentioned in your comment, I would recommend act_as_audited

http://github.com/collectiveidea/acts_as_audited

We are using it successfully for a very large application.

Peer

Comment: This only adds who did a certain action (updater, deleter, creator), but no track of what was actually updated. But maybe this is enough for the OP?

Answer (score 1):

The plugins you mentioned all seem to take the same approach, and seem to be somewhat similar in approach: use a seperate table to store the old versions.

None of them seem to be really rails3-ready (looking at the generators), but PaperTrail reportedly should work with rails3, and has the most recent commit.

You could also look at the ruby-toolbox [user-stamping](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/activerecord_user_stamping.html) and [versioning](http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/activerecord_versioning.html). There you can see which project has the most "traction", which has the most recent commits. Which sometimes can help to make a choice between similar options.

Comment: I use papertrail in a Rails 3 project without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) is what you need to solve this problem.

With [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) you can track and see all changes ,to any model, with user id of who made the changes.

It is currently the best maintained project of the three you linked

Answer (score 0):

HI @viatropos I thought that these two links might prove to be helpful

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html

http://www.robbyonrails.com/articles/2007/04/27/observers-big-and-small